# Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online) Custom Reporting

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Anybody has any idea how to do custom reporting in Team Services without help of Power BI. I can get the test cases and defect data from Excel Add-In but this is not useful as we have to write the Team Services Query all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some lightweight charts and dashboards you can use for the report, refer to this link for details: [Dashboards and reports overview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/overview).

And beside the Power BI, Analytics service is added to VSTS but it is in preview for now. If you are interested in it, you can contact the Analytics service team: vsts-analytics-supp@microsoft.com.